# Using jQuery to get the width of each element in a list

Tags: jquery, width, each

I am trying to get the width value of each list item in an element but it keeps returning the object and not the width.  This should be really simple but for some reason I must be missing something.

Here is my code:

```
    var listWidth = $('ul li').each(function(){
        return $(this).width();
    });

    console.log(listWidth);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method instead to return the values to a jQuery object, then the [`get()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to convert it to an Array.

```
var listWidth = $('ul li').map(function(){
    return $(this).width();
}).get();
```

Or similar, you can use the [`jQuery.map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method, which returns an Array.

```
var listWidth = $.map($('ul li'),function(val){
    return $(val).width();
});
```

Comment: beaten by 30s. You can have the rest of the questions.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the answer. Not sure where the .get() came from. This is not an AJAX request.

Comment: @ThePixelProdigy: What AJAX request? My answer doesn't have anything to do with AJAX.

Comment: Apparently, jQuery has 2 .get() functions (just like how it has 2 .load() functions). [One function](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is used the way you used it in your answer, while [another one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is used for AJAX requests.

Answer (score 3):

You can get them by pushing the values to an array also:

```
var listWidth = [];
$('ul li').each(function() {
    listWidth.push($(this).width());
});

console.log(listWidth);
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/pAgud/)

Answer (score -1):

Since you will have multiple list items, you can create an array of widths as you go:

```
var listWidth = [];
$('ul li').each(function(){
    listWidth.push($(this).width());
});

console.log(listWidth);
```

Or, instead, you could create an object with the widths:

```
var listWidth = {};
$('ul li').each(function(){
    listWidth[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).width();
});

console.log(listWidth);
```

This example creates an object that contains the id of the tag and its width (`{ id1: width, id2: width, etc...}`, assuming each tag has an id).

The example code you posted had the problem that, when returning the width, it was returning it to the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function (which probably just discarded it), but `listWidth` was the return value of the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function, not the anonymous function inside (so, since the each function returns a jQuery object, that is what was assigned to listWidth).